Problems with inaccurate transcriptions using DeepSpeech model
I'm using DeepSpeech to transcribe audio files but keep getting gibberish or repeated characters (e.g., "e e e e") instead of proper text.
Here's the process:
Read the audio file using Node.js fs.readFileSync.
Convert to base64.
Pass it to model.stt() for transcription.
The audio is in the correct format (FLAC), yet the output is invalid. Could someone help troubleshoot this or suggest improvements? Specifically, I'm looking for:
Best practices for preparing audio files for DeepSpeech.
Reasons for repeated characters in transcriptions.
Configuration tips to improve accuracy.
Sample code snippet:
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const app = express();
const upload = multer({ dest: 'audios/' });
const path = require('path');
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
const DeepSpeech = require('deepspeech');

const modelUrl = 'models/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm';
const scorerPath = 'models/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer';

const model = new DeepSpeech.Model(modelUrl);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

app.post('/censor', upload.single('audio'), (req, res) => {
    console.log("Censoring...");

    function generateRandomFileName(extension) {
        console.log("Generating file name...");
        const randomString = crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('hex');
        const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        const fileName = `${timestamp}-${randomString}${extension}`;
        return fileName;
    }

    console.log("Convert to .flac...");
    let filePath = req.file.path;
    let fileName = generateRandomFileName('.flac');

    console.log("Mono channeling and .flac save...");
    ffmpeg(filePath)
        .audioChannels(1)
        .audioFrequency(16000)
        .format('flac')
        .save('outputs/' + fileName)
        .on('end', async () => {
            const file = fs.readFileSync('outputs/' + fileName);
            const audioBytes = file.toString('base64');

            console.log("Encoding audio...");
            const audio = {
                content: audioBytes,
            };
            const config = {
                encoding: 'WAV',
                sampleRateHertz: 16000,
                languageCode: 'en-US',
            };
            const request = {
                audio: audio,
                config: config,
            };

            console.log("Performing speech recognition...");
            const audioBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
            const results = model.stt(audioBuffer);
            const transcription = results;
            console.log("Transcription: " + transcription);

            console.log("Checking for curse words...");
            let words = transcription.split(' ');

            let curseWords = [];
            
            for (let word of words) {
                if (curseWords.includes(word.toLowerCase())) {
                    console.log("Curse word detected: " + word);
                    return res.status(200).send("Curse word detected: " + word);
                }
            }

            console.log("No curse words detected.");
            return res.status(200).send('No curse words detected.');
        });
});


What happens with a sampling rate of 32K, 64K?
